# how to implement spark sql pagination query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does anyone how to do pagination in spark sql query?

I need to use spark sql but don't know how to do pagination.

Tried:

```
select * from person limit 10, 10
```

Answer (score 7):

It has been 6 years, don't know if it was possible back then.

I would **add a sequential id** on the answer and search for registers **between** offset and offset + limit

On pure Spark SQL query it would be something like this, for offset 10 and limit 10

```sql
WITH count_person AS (
    SELECT *, monotonically_increasing_id() AS count FROM person)
SELECT * FROM count_person WHERE count > 10 AND count < 20
```

On PySpark it would be very similar

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

offset = 10
limit = 10
df = df.withColumn('_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df = df.where(F.col('_id').between(offset, offset + limit))
```

It's flexible and fast enough even for a big volume of data.

Comment: Note that "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive". So you can risk having a sequence of integers which are not used as IDs, and then some larger integers which again are used.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but this means that the whole data will be reloaded for each page?

Answer (score 3):

[karthik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33516696/3534616) will fail if there are duplicate rows in the dataframe. 'except' will remove all rows in df1 which are in df2 .

```
val filteredRdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().collect { case (r, i) if 10 >= start && i <=20 => r }
val newDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(filteredRdd, df.schema)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for offset as of now in spark sql. One of the alternatives you can use for paging is through `DataFrames` using `except` method.

Example: You want to iterate with a paging limit of 10, you can do the following:

```
    DataFrame df1;
    long count = df.count();
    int limit = 10;
    while(count > 0){
        df1 = df.limit(limit);
        df1.show();            //will print 10, next 10, etc rows
        df = df.except(df1);
        count = count - limit;
    }
```

If you want to do say,  `LIMIT 50, 100` in the first go, you can do the following:

```
        df1 = df.limit(50);
        df2 = df.except(df1);
        df2.limit(100);       //required result
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will fail if there are duplicate rows in the dataframe. 'except' will remove all rows  in df1 which are in df2

Answer (score 1):

Please find bellow a useful PySpark (Python 3 and Spark 3) class named **SparkPaging** which abstract the pagination mecanism :
https://gitlab.com/enahwe/public/lib/spark/sparkpaging

Here's the usage :

## SparkPaging

Class for paging dataframes and datasets

### Example

**- Init example 1:**

Approach by specifying a limit.

```py
sp = SparkPaging(initData=df, limit=753)
```

**- Init example 2:**

Approach by specifying a number of pages (if there's a rest, the number of pages will be incremented).

```py
sp = SparkPaging(initData=df, pages=6)
```

**- Init example 3:**

Approach by specifying a limit.

```py
sp = SparkPaging()
sp.init(initData=df, limit=753)
```

**- Init example 4:**

Approach by specifying a number of pages (if there's a rest, the number of pages will be incremented).

```py
sp = SparkPaging()
sp.init(initData=df, pages=6)
```

**- Reset:**

```py
sp.reset()
```

**- Iterate example:**

```py
print("- Total number of rows = " + str(sp.initDataCount))
print("- Limit = " + str(sp.limit))
print("- Number of pages = " + str(sp.pages))
print("- Number of rows in the last page = " + str(sp.numberOfRowsInLastPage))
while (sp.page < sp.pages-1):
    df_page = sp.next()
    nbrRows = df_page.count()
    print("  Page " + str(sp.page) + '/' + str(sp.pages) + ": Number of rows = " + str(nbrRows))
```

**- Output:**

```
- Total number of rows = 4521
- Limit = 753
- Number of pages = 7
- Number of rows in the last page = 3
    Page 0/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 1/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 2/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 3/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 4/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 5/7: Number of rows = 753
    Page 6/7: Number of rows = 3
```

Comment: The syntax is convenient but the logic behind quite inefficient

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner, easier and lazier way is always the best: use offset and limit, introduced recently in Spark 3.4.

```py
fullDF = ...
total = fullDF.count()
counter = 0
pageSize = 10
while counter < total:
   pageDF = fullDF.offset(counter*pageSize).limit(pageSize)
   ...
   counter += 1
```