# Apache Spark page results or view results on large datasets

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am using Hive with Spark 1.6.3

I have a large dataset (40000 rows, 20 columns or so and each column contains maybe 500 Bytes - 3KB of data)

The query is a join to 3 datasets

I wish to be able to page the final join dataset, and i have found that i can use `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1)` to generate a unique row number for each row in the dataset.

After this I can do

```sql
SELECT * FROM dataset WHERE row between 1 AND 100
```

However, there are resources which advise not to use `ORDER BY` as it puts all data into 1 partition (I can see this is the case in the logs where the shuffle allocation is moving the data to one partition), when this happens I get out of memory exceptions.

How would i go about paging through the dataset in a more efficient way?

I have enabled persist - `MEMORY_AND_DISK` so that if a partition is too large it will spill to disk (and for some of the transformation I can see that at least some of the data is spilling to disk when I am not using `row_number()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One strategy could be select only the unique_key of the dataset first and apply row_number function on that dataset only. Since you are selecting a single column from a large dataset chances are higher that it will fit in a single partition.

```
val dfKey = df.select("uniqueKey")
dfKey.createOrUpdateTempTable("dfKey")
val dfWithRowNum = spark.sql(select dfKey*, row_number() as row_number OVER (ORDER BY 1))
// save dfWithRowNum
```

After to complete the row_number operation on the uniqueKey; save that dataframe. Now in the next stage join this dataframe with the bigger dataframe and append the row_number column to that.

```
dfOriginal.createOrUpdateTempTable("dfOriginal")
dfWithRowNum.createOrUpdateTempTable("dfWithRowNum")
val joined = spark.sql("select dfOriginal.* from dfOriginal join dfWithRowNum on dfOriginal.uniqueKey = dfWithRowNum.uniqueKey")
// save joined
```

Now you can query

```
SELECT * FROM joineddataset WHERE row between 1 AND 100
```

For the persist with MEMORY_DISK, I found that occasionally fail with insufficient memory. I would rather use DISK_ONLY where performance is penalized although the execution is guaranteed.

Comment: thanks for help, this is ok when there is a unique key, but in the case there is not a unique key?

Comment: just for information this could be applied with adding a unique reference ID to the dfOriginal table - and this could be used as the primaryID even if there is no natural primary id from the data itself. e.g. SELECT reflect('java.util.UUID', 'randomUUID') AS PrimaryID from dfOriginal

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can apply [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37110484/4411193) on your final join dataframe.

You should also persist the dataframe as a file to guarantee the ordering, as reevaluation could creates a [different order](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@zipWithIndex():org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(T,Long)]).